# Mongodb query nested array documents where property not null

Tags: mongodb

I am trying to get all the documents where at least one element of the instock collection has the warehouse field not null. Expected result: discard only the last documents.

```
db.inventory.insertMany( [
   { item: "journal", instock: [ { warehouse: "A", qty: 5 }, { warehouse: "C", qty: 15 } ] },
   { item: "notebook", instock: [ { warehouse: "C", qty: 5 } ] },
   { item: "planner", instock: [ { warehouse: null, qty: 40 }, { warehouse: "B", qty: 5 } ] },
   { item: "postcard", instock: [ { warehouse: null, qty: 15 }, { warehouse: null, qty: 35 } ] }
]);
```

This query discards the 3 and 4.

```
db.getCollection('inventory').find({
    $and: [{"instock.warehouse": {$ne: null}}, {"instock.warehouse": {$exists: true}}]
})
```

This one returns all the elements

```
db.getCollection('inventory').find({
    "instock": {$elemMatch: {"warehouse": {$ne: null}, "warehouse": {$exists: true}}}
})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use below find query.

Note the use of `$elemMatch` & `$ne` which compares all the elements of array 
 i.e. includes all the documents where instock array don't have at least one null value in warehouse field.

```
db.inventory.find({"instock":{"$elemMatch":{"warehouse":{"$ne":null}}}})
```